# How to debug visual studio code extension in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, vscode-extensions, npm-scripts

I have a visual studio code extension, but usually I develop in java so I'm much more experienced in intellij IDEA than vs code. So my question is, is there a way to debug my vs code extension in intellij?

Intellij has plugins for compiling and run typescript programs, it also supports node development.
I think I should create an npm run configuration, where I put npm compile script from package.json to before launch section and then run another npm script that will launch the vs code with the compiled extension. But I don't actually know how this script should look like, or if there is a better way to go.

Comment: Hey, did you find a proper solution for this?

Comment: Hi, I've tried to import libraries and run classes individually as @Akhri bar suggested, but in the end, I found it much more comfortable to just use vscode it provides full support without any extra configuration. Although it was several years ago, it is worth checking out the new plugins,  somebody may have uploaded something.

Comment: Any luck? Been trying for a couple hours with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing all the libraries first.

InelliJ has an excellent feature of running each and every method and class individually, use that feature,
To use that feature, there is a green triangle at the right side, click on that to debug

Comment: Importing libraries is useful for debugging, but the challenge here is actually connecting to the VSC debugger.